# Update a row and all 'parents' (if exists)

Tags: sql, sql-server, parent, cascade

i need a help to do a query where i update a row initially based on the description and all *parents*, if exists.

**My table** ***ItemMenu:***

**Id**

**DescName**

**IdParent**

**BolActive**

So, i need activate (set BolActive = 1) a row where *description* i'll inform in the query and then update all the rows if IdParent is not null/blank and if it exists in the same table (IdParent = Id).

Something like:

**Update ItemMenu set BolActive = 1 where DescName = 'MyMenu'**

then i need to check if IdParent from **Select * from ItemMenu where DescName = 'MyMenu'** exists

If yes, i'll **Update ItemMenu set BolActive = 1 where IdParent (from the previous select) = Id** and check again if IdParent exists here... until IdParent is null/blank and it stops

Is it possible?

P.s. I can't change table structure.

Comment: Sure it is possible. You can do this with a recursive cte. If you need some help then it would be most helpful if you could post ddl and some sample data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming I understand the desired code result, try an update using a recursive common table expression. Provided a screenshot. Apologies for my noob text formatting.

http://s12.postimg.org/cw8yz0isd/Capture.jpg

```
DECLARE @description AS VARCHAR(50) = 'Hello World'

;WITH CTE AS (

    SELECT  Menu.*
    FROM    dbo.ItemMenu Menu
    WHERE   Menu.descname = @description
    UNION   ALL
    SELECT  Menu2.*
    FROM    dbo.ItemMenu Menu2
    JOIN    CTE
    ON      Menu2.idParent = CTE.Id
)
Update  ActualMenu
SET     BolActive = 1 
FROM    CTE Menu
JOIN    dbo.ItemMenu ActualMenu
ON      ActualMenu.Id = Menu.Id
```

Comment: Worked very well, i just changed
    "ON      Menu2.idParent = CTE.Id"
to
    "ON      Menu2.id = CTE.idParent"

 . Thank you o/

Comment: Yeah woops sorry about that mixup. Glad you figured that out.